# Set passes Dieharder randomness with ints values, fails when ints are split into bytes

Tags: random-number-generator

I've generated 100M of random numbers in range (0..255). These numbers fail Dieharder tasts (bitnum = 8). However, I can pass this test by combining four bytes into an int. 
Randomness of the set didn't change, so, something isn't correct with the test settings. What could cause it?

```
    def prep_input(file_name, number_of_iterations,numbit=32):
        f = open(file_name, "a")            
        max_rand = (-1 + 2 ** numbit)
        print(str(max_rand))
        a = len(str(max_rand))
        for i in range(0, number_of_iterations):
            f.write(str(randint(0, max_rand)).rjust(a) + "\n")

        f1.close()
```

With header it looks like

```
#==================================================================
# Dieharder
#==================================================================
type: d
count: 16180337
numbit: 8
255
  0
 93
 ....
```

`dieharder -a -g 202 -f   input.txt >>result.txt`

Report on bytes:  [Set fails when bytes are used](https://pastebin.com/rkbJ1smC)
Report on ints: [Set passes tests when ints are used](https://pastebin.com/N8TX9UJy)

---

Update:

- I've tested up to 4Gb of data. This is close to 2^32 although ASCII format requires ~4 characters (4 bytes) per a byte of actual data.
- When this file is converted to byte stream it passws several tests and then reaches the end of data. When concatinated it passes tests better than ASCII int version.
- When Python random is fed as a binary to

  import time
  import sys
  import os
  from random import randint

  j=0
  div = 2

  while(True):
      sys.stdout.write(chr(randint(0, 255)))
      # newFileBytes = [randint(0, 255)]
      # os.write(1, (''.join(chr(i) for i in newFileBytes)).encode('charmap'))
      sys.stdout.flush()
      j+=1

  ```
  if 0 == j%div :
      dh_file = open("progress.log", "a")
      dh_file.write(str(j)+"\n")
      dh_file.close()
      div = div*2
  ```

With `python to_terminal.py  |  dieharder -a -g 200 >>test_result.dhres` I get 16G  (17179869184) as the last record in the log and out of 75 tests only two tests are weak the rest is a pass.  [Python passes DH when supplied as bit stream](https://pastebin.com/ry6VNyfS) Clearly, the problem follows 8 bit ASCII representation.

Comment: Randomness is fundamentally impossible to *measure*. All statistical tests simply *estimate* randomness in different ways. I don't think it's surprising that different statistical tests produce different results. (Concretely, the output does look like something may be wrong, though.)

Comment: Standard PRNG, 90% increase in pass rate thanks to data aggregation? There must be something wrong with the DH run parameters.

Comment: Feel free to comment downvotes.

Comment: Run the basic ENT test across your bytified data.  If it passes, you've done the Dieharder test wrong. If it fails ENT badly, you've converted the data wrong. Then take it from there...

Comment: `dieharder -a` requires much more data (in the order of $2^{32}$ bytes), see citations from the manual [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61339/555). Also, testing a would-be CS(P)RNG using Diehard is somewhat like testing a [bathyscaphe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathyscaphe) in a pool: not detecting a failure allows to draw no operational conclusion.

Comment: @fgrieu  "bathyscaphe in a pool" (sanity test) is informative in this case. Turns out that bathyscaphe sinks if the hatch is open (bytes written as ASCII), but remains operational with hatch close (int representation). Did it convey any information? Sure. When we test bathyscaphe in high seas we must make sure that the hath is closed. Flipping from 90% fail to 90% pass - DH clearly misunderstands the format of data and this have nothing to do with Python generator itself.