# How to compute the dataset size required by dieharder tests?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy, statistical-test, trng

I am trying to use the [dieharder](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php) random number test suite.

However, this suite requires massive amount of data ([this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-10591-4_10) claims 228GB for no rewinding for every test) for most of the tests. I'd like to understand how rewinding is implemented and to know how much data is required for each test. It seems related to the *tsamples* value but I cannot find an exact correlation.

For example, if I generate 400MiB of data using `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.dat bs=1M count=400`, this produces the following (cropped) output:

```
$ dieharder -a -g 201 -f random.dat
#=============================================================================#
#            dieharder version 3.31.1 Copyright 2003 Robert G. Brown          #
#=============================================================================#
   rng_name    |           filename             |rands/second|
 file_input_raw|                      random.dat|  6.38e+07  |
#=============================================================================#
        test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment
#=============================================================================#
   diehard_birthdays|   0|       100|     100|0.70238534|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 1 times
      diehard_operm5|   0|   1000000|     100|0.74169241|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 2 times
  diehard_rank_32x32|   0|     40000|     100|0.03164866|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 2 times
    diehard_rank_6x8|   0|    100000|     100|0.18168084|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 3 times
   diehard_bitstream|   0|   2097152|     100|0.59056568|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 5 times
        diehard_opso|   0|   2097152|     100|0.19175240|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 6 times
        diehard_oqso|   0|   2097152|     100|0.67542036|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 7 times
         diehard_dna|   0|   2097152|     100|0.04906220|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 7 times
diehard_count_1s_str|   0|    256000|     100|0.80349572|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 8 times
diehard_count_1s_byt|   0|    256000|     100|0.43003125|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 8 times
 diehard_parking_lot|   0|     12000|     100|0.07270933|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 8 times
    diehard_2dsphere|   2|      8000|     100|0.92548415|  PASSED
```

I assume that dieharder just loops over the file, keeping its pointer position when jumping to the next test and that `The file file_input_raw was rewound N times` is just the total count that the pointer reached the end of the file.

Comment: I think it uses 32-bits samples so the input size needs to be $4 bytes \times tsamples \times psamples$.

Comment: If I am correct, the total amount of rewinds is not important as long as each test has an input larger than $4 \times tsamples \times psamples$.

Comment: [That question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61339/555) may help, and at least my answer gives a value (2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) = 16 Gib) that seems to work in practice. I don't know why you try to use dieharder for, but if it's to test the output of a CSPRNG: passing the test is not useful indication that the CSPRNG is theoretically correct, much less that it is correctly seeded and practically secure. This extends to other crypto algorithms. And, independently: the best option might be to remove the tests that require more data than available.

Comment: Note that you can pipe input into dieharder from your program or entropy source so there is no need to precompute and store a file.

Comment: @Boann  Hiya!  All well and good for the Hadron Collider team, but most DIY generateurs are severely constrained in the entropy rate.  So free running or pre-computing ~250 GB of samples is equally difficult. This then is a neat segue as to what is the purpose of 250 GB of entropy?

Answer (score 5):

I'll be so bold as to say that no one knows for sure how much data you really need. There is no guidance on the [homepage](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/General/dieharder.php), the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder) and [this](https://lists.phy.duke.edu/pipermail/dieharder-devel/2018-August/thread.html) thread from Duke is equally unspecific. Anecdotal evidence suggests that a 'few' GB will return a sane PASS/FAIL answer, but there will still be rewinds. For a 4 GB `/dev/urandom` test:-

```
...snip
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 43 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  27|   1000000|     100|0.75608263|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 46 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  28|   1000000|     100|0.88574962|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 49 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  29|   1000000|     100|0.69532845|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 52 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  30|   1000000|     100|0.93874399|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 55 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  31|   1000000|     100|0.59282678|  PASSED  
# The file file_input_raw was rewound 58 times
      rgb_lagged_sum|  32|   1000000|     100|0.88988310|  PASSED
```

58 times!

In your case (input file), a rewind is just that; start again from the beginning. Eight rewinds is good. I've seen [1849](https://lists.phy.duke.edu/pipermail/dieharder-devel/2018-August/000097.html) rewinds. Honestly I can't understand the reasoning behind that, as all it does is retest what's been tested.

And that could be good or bad as is illustrated with the following walk over a random source. If you test and rewind the contents of box A you might expect a pass. Conversely if you test and rewind box B, monobit and runs tests are likely to fail due to the large 3:1 bias in the x axis. Repetitive rewinding clearly can't help the p values, so perhaps we need a larger sample size such as box C.

[image: walk]

All we know for certain is that Dieharder uses a lot. Your [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-10591-4_10) and [my](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61546/23115) research shows that a free run of Dieharder (with no rewinds) needs approximately 225 - 250 GB! Notice that $58 \times 4 \text{GB}= 232 \text{GB}$.

There are other tests though. A more common test in the TRNG scientific literature is NIST's [Statistical Test Suite](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-22/rev-1a/final), (SP 800-22). It's sample requirements are much more predictable.

And now a warning. You have to resist manipulating any randomness tests in order to get a PASS. Tweaking test parameters or selectively choosing individual tests to produce your expected result is dangerous, as a random sample is random no matter how you test it. From the manpage:-

> ...where a file that is too small will "rewind" and render the test results where a rewind occurs suspect.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a precise, hopefully definitive answer we can count the number of rewinds for each test. I generated a 1KiB file that was used as an input.

After some source code investigation, *dieharder* treats input files as a stream that is consumed indefinitely so every new test resumes the stream at the same place where the previous test stopped. Interestingly, *dieharder* has is an `-s` strategy flag:

> if strategy is the (default) 0, dieharder reseeds (or
> rewinds) once at the beginning when the random number generator is
> selected and then never again.  If strategy is nonzero, the generator
> is reseeded or rewound at the beginning of EACH TEST.  If [...] a file is used, this means every test is applied to the
> same sequence (which is useful for validation and testing of dieharder,
> but not a good way to test rngs).

So running `dieharder -a -g 201 -s 1 -f kibibyte.dat` ([full output](https://pastebin.com/raw/WTsx7EfA)) produces the following data:

| test_name | ntup | tsamples | psamples | rewinds for 1 KiB | remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| diehard_birthdays | 0 | 100 | 100 | 15000 |  |
| diehard_operm5 | 0 | 1000000 | 100 | 390626 |  |
| diehard_rank_32x32 | 0 | 40000 | 100 | 500000 |  |
| diehard_rank_6x8 | 0 | 100000 | 100 | 234375 |  |
| diehard_bitstream | 0 | 2097152 | 100 | 102400 |  |
| diehard_opso | 0 | 2097152 | 100 | 819200 |  |
| diehard_oqso | 0 | 2097152 | 100 | 546134 |  |
| diehard_dna | 0 | 2097152 | 100 | 256004 |  |
| diehard_count_1s_str | 0 | 256000 | 100 | 25000 |  |
| diehard_count_1s_byt | 0 | 256000 | 100 | 500000 |  |
| diehard_parking_lot | 0 | 12000 | 100 | 9375 |  |
| diehard_2dsphere | 2 | 8000 | 100 | 6250 |  |
| diehard_3dsphere | 3 | 4000 | 100 | 4687 |  |
| diehard_squeeze | 0 | 100000 | 100 | 909090 |  |
| diehard_sums | 0 | 100 | 100 | 77 |  |
| diehard_runs | 0 | 100000 | 100 | 39062 | test ran 2x |
| diehard_craps | 0 | 200000 | 100 | 526315 | test ran 2x |
| marsaglia_tsang_gcd | 0 | 10000000 | 100 | 7812500 | test ran 2x |
| sts_monobit | 1 | 100000 | 100 | 39062 |  |
| sts_runs | 2 | 100000 | 100 | 39062 |  |
| sts_serial | 1-16 | 100000 | 100 | 39062 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 1 | 100000 | 100 | 78125 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 2 | 100000 | 100 | 156250 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 3 | 100000 | 100 | 234375 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 4 | 100000 | 100 | 312500 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 5 | 100000 | 100 | 390625 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 6 | 100000 | 100 | 468750 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 7 | 100000 | 100 | 546875 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 8 | 100000 | 100 | 625000 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 9 | 100000 | 100 | 703125 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 10 | 100000 | 100 | 781250 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 11 | 100000 | 100 | 859375 |  |
| rgb_bitdist | 12 | 100000 | 100 | 937500 |  |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 2 | 10000 | 1000 | 78125 |  |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 3 | 10000 | 1000 | 117187 |  |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 4 | 10000 | 1000 | 156250 |  |
| rgb_minimum_distance | 5 | 10000 | 1000 | 195312 |  |
| rgb_permutations | 2 | 100000 | 100 | 78125 |  |
| rgb_permutations | 3 | 100000 | 100 | 117187 |  |
| rgb_permutations | 4 | 100000 | 100 | 156250 |  |
| rgb_permutations | 5 | 100000 | 100 | 195312 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 0 | 1000000 | 100 | 390625 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 1 | 1000000 | 100 | 781250 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 2 | 1000000 | 100 | 1171875 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 3 | 1000000 | 100 | 1562500 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 4 | 1000000 | 100 | 1953125 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 5 | 1000000 | 100 | 2343750 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 6 | 1000000 | 100 | 2734375 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 7 | 1000000 | 100 | 3125000 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 8 | 1000000 | 100 | 3515625 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 9 | 1000000 | 100 | 3906250 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 10 | 1000000 | 100 | 4296875 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 11 | 1000000 | 100 | 4687500 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 12 | 1000000 | 100 | 5078125 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 13 | 1000000 | 100 | 5468750 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 14 | 1000000 | 100 | 5859375 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 15 | 1000000 | 100 | 6250000 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 16 | 1000000 | 100 | 6640625 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 17 | 1000000 | 100 | 7031250 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 18 | 1000000 | 100 | 7421875 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 19 | 1000000 | 100 | 7812500 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 20 | 1000000 | 100 | 8203125 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 21 | 1000000 | 100 | 8593750 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 22 | 1000000 | 100 | 8984375 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 23 | 1000000 | 100 | 9375000 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 24 | 1000000 | 100 | 9765625 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 25 | 1000000 | 100 | 10156250 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 26 | 1000000 | 100 | 10546875 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 27 | 1000000 | 100 | 10937500 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 28 | 1000000 | 100 | 11328125 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 29 | 1000000 | 100 | 11718750 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 30 | 1000000 | 100 | 12109375 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 31 | 1000000 | 100 | 12500000 |  |
| rgb_lagged_sum | 32 | 1000000 | 100 | 12890625 |  |
| rgb_kstest_test | 0 | 10000 | 1000 | 39062 |  |
| dab_bytedistrib | 0 | 51200000 | 1 | 600000 |  |
| dab_dct | 256 | 50000 | 1 | 50000 |  |
| dab_filltree | 32 | 15000000 | 1 | 422619 | test ran 2x |
| dab_filltree2 | 0-1 | 5000000 | 1 | 113636 |  |
| dab_monobit2 | 12 | 65000000 | 1 | 253906 |  |

The test which requires the largest amount of data is `rgb_lagged_sum` which requires 13.2 GB when ntup=32. Ignoring other instances of `rgb_lagged_sum`, the second and third test with largest input are `marsaglia_tsang_gcd` which requires 8GB and then `rgb_bitdist` which requires 960MB.

An interesting take on this is that rewinds do not influence the outcome above 13.2GB (but some tests will reuse the same sequence).

Comment: Should compact the table and add the equivalent in MB in a column.

Answer (score 0):

The [TestU01](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html) suite for testing pseudorandom number generators incorporates tests from DieHarder (all of them, I think).  On pages 5 and 6 of the journal article on the TestU01 suite (see link near bottom of same page), L'Ecuyer and Simard explain that it makes sense to test until the p-values are incredibly small, or continue to remain relatively large.  In the former case, the PRNG fails the test; in the latter case, it doesn't.  If the p-values are small but not very small, one can re-test several times with disjoint generated sequences "until either failure becomes obvious or suspicion disappears" (p. 5). The same informal principle applies to the subset of TestU01 contained in DieHarder.  TestU01 also includes a set of modules intended for the purpose of finding "prediction formulas for the sample size $n_0$ for which the test starts to reject an RNG decisively, as a function of its period length $\rho$" (p. 25).

Of course your random source has to be capable producing that much data without repeating itself, as your question reflects, but DieHarder and TestU01 were designed for modern pseudorandom number generating algorithms with very large periods, i.e. no rewinding--if I understand the terminology in the question--for many steps.

As @fgrieu's comment indicates, passing DieHarder or TestU01 doesn't tell you anything about cryptographic security, but I'm assuming that you're using DieHarder to test whether RNG output satisfies other, non-cryptographic, criteria for RNG quality.

@PaulUszak's answer suggests the NIST SP800-22 suite for cryptographic security properties.  Please see @fgrieu's comment below as well.  Johnston's book [Random Number Generators—Principles and Practices](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781501506062/html) contains an extended survey of SP800-22.

Comment: I don't agree that "the NIST SP800-22 suite (…) clearly is designed to test for cryptographic security". The closest I know to a stated design goal is _"These tests may be useful as a first step in determining whether or not a generator is suitable for a particular cryptographic application"_. And it's not like the NIST always states their true design goals. Dual_EC_DRBG passes NIST SP800-22! What's clear is that passing the NIST SP800-22 suite, or any test based on the output of a CSPRNG or conditioned TRNG, is not a useful indication that it is practically secure.

Comment: Ah, OK, good.  Thanks @fgrieu.  I'll edit my answer to point to your comment.

Comment: Re: _" On pages 5 and 6... "_.  How do you figure?  Correctly determined p values are uniformly distributed as $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$. I can't see how they could _stabilise_. p has to vary randomly, irrespective of sample size, no?

Comment: Thanks @PaulUszak.  The way that I put it was incorrect.  I've now rewritten that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the [example](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dieharder), they said:

> type: d
> count: 100000
> numbit: 32

so I assume the count of 1000000 is sufficient for the ascii formatted.